# How to Identify the Test Code Written for trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test

Can any one help me.I have written a Trigger and test classes .When i check in the sandbox i could see only the trigger and the test classes got disapperared .I checked in the Apex classes and in Developer Console to run the test.But i could not see the test class.Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could run all tests  in the developer console (by clicking on Test > Run All), once they are complete you can then see the coverage for a particular class and where/what generated the coverage:

[image]

This will only help if the test class actually provides coverage and hasn't been deleted/commented out...oh and make sure it's got the @isTest annotation